# How to auto line break in bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm setting "overflow scroll able" option. I want setting this overflow option of only y scrolling and if x content overflow so, line break.

I apply 'white-space'. but, can't applicable.

```html
<ul class="sidebar-menu scrollable" style="height: calc(100% - 130px);">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="sidebar-link">
            <span class="title">
                <div id="desc-viewer" class="desc-viewer" style="">
                     <!-- markdown datas... -->
                     <!-- example data -->
                     <pre class="prettyprint linenums">
                        <code>
                        Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax!
                        </code>
                     </pre>
                </div>
             </span>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This code result is create overflow-x scroll.

Comment: try with `white-space: pre-wrap;` on `pre` tag

Comment: Try adding `white-space: normal;` to your `prettyprint linenums` class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `word-break` property.

```css
.alas {
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

```html
<p class="alas">Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.Hi,Thisisme.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS property `word-wrap:break-word`.

```css
div {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>DSCSNKCSKCSCMSKCSKCSKCNSKCNSKCNKSCNSKCNSKCNSKCNSKCNSKCNSKNCKSCNKSNCKSCNSCNKSKCSNCKSKNCSKNCSKCNKSKCNSKNCSKNCKSNCSNKCKCNNSKCNSCNKSCNKSNCK</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[word-break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/word-break)property helps you to fix this

```css
p {
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<p>VDAAAAAAAAAAJCAJANVAKVJNAKVAKVNAKVNAKVAAAAAAAAAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAVANVALKVMAJLIILVEAJAJALVNALIVNALKVAKLNVANAKLVNANAVLJANVLAKSVSAKLVASKLVAKLVALKVAKNVAS</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have use `<pre>` to contain your text,
you can try `white-space: pre-wrap;`

If you do not want the tab infront, you can try `white-space: pre-line;`

```css
#pre-wrap {
    white-space: pre-wrap;
}

#pre-line {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div id="desc-viewer" class="desc-viewer" style="">
     <pre id="pre-wrap"class="prettyprint linenums">
        <code>
        Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! est syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! est syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax!
        </code>
     </pre>
     
     
       <pre id="pre-line" class="prettyprint linenums">
        <code>
        Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! est syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! est syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax! Test syntax!
        </code>
     </pre>
</div>
```